# Comment traduirait-on le verbe « to speed read » en français ?

Tags: traduction, vocabulaire, anglais

> [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/speed-read)
>
> **speed read** verb [ I or T ] (also speed-read) uk /ˈspiːd ˌriːd/ us /ˈspiːd ˌriːd/
> to read and understand written texts faster than normal, often using particular techniques (= methods) that can be learned:
> • He published a paper reviewing what the latest science can tell us about attempts to speed read.
> • I read to 50% and speed read/skimmed the rest to see if I was missing out on a great read.
> • She just had time to speed-read the first Harry Potter novel before trying out for the part.

On trouve souvent la traduction « lire à toute vitesse », mais ça correspond à « lire très vite sans trop bien lire ». Ce n'est pas le sens le plus usuel qui est codifié par « speed read ».

([Linguee](https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/speed+read.html)) Since I speed-read my presentation, I have 30 seconds. →
Étant donné que j'ai lu mon exposé à toute vitesse, j'ai 30 secondes.

On trouve des traductions similaires (lire vite, lire rapidement) dans [reverso](https://context.reverso.net/traduction/anglais-francais/speed-read).

[Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/spellcheck/french-english?q=speed+read) n'a pas de traduction. [Word Reference](https://www.wordreference.com/enfr/speed%20read) n'a pas d'entrée pour ce terme.

Le Larousse, qui semble vouloir éviter cet écueil, propose l'option de définition suivante.

> ([Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/speed-read/1000949))  lire selon la méthode de lecture rapide

Ce n'est cependant pas une expression facile à utiliser vu sa longueur. Quelqu'un aurait-t-il la connaissance d'un  néologisme qui serait plus pratique pour traduire « speed read » ?

Comment: Si j'entrevoyais la moindre possibilité je le ferais mais je ne vois pas cela comme une bonne solution ;  il faut laisser « lecture rapide » de côté à mon avis.

Answer (score 3):

En français, on dit souvent "**lire en diagonale**", qui correspondrait plutôt à "skim read". Il s'agirait alors de lire très rapidement un texte en en comprenant les grandes lignes, sans pour autant mémoriser tout ce qui a été écrit.

Je sais qu'il existe des concours de [lecture rapide](https://www.maformation.fr/actualites/comment-apprendre-lecture-rapide-54499) qui consiste à lire et mémoriser un texte le plus rapidement possible. Si tu souhaites dire "lire à toute vitesse et comprendre le tout *comme si j'avais lu normalement*", je rejoins l'avis de @mastödantirâfamî. Dans le cas contraire (et ça se prête davantage à la lecture d'articles scientifiques par exemple) je dirais plutôt "lire en diagonale".

Comment: Expression intéressante par l'image qu'elle communique.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai pas de néologisme à proposer, mais la proposition de *Larousse* peut se réduire avec le semi-auxiliaire *faire* : « faire de la lecture rapide ». On peut se demander quelle préposition chosir par ailleurs. Autrement il faut reformuler :

> ...à propos des tentatives de faire de la lecture rapide.
> ...et j'ai fait de la lecture rapide avec/pour le reste, j'ai parcouru rapidement, j'ai fait un survol etc.
> ...elle n'a eu que le temps de passer à travers le premier tome d'Harry Potter en lecture rapide...
> Étant donné que j'ai fait la lecture rapide de mon exposé à toute vitesse, j'ai 30 secondes.
> Étant donné que j'ai lu mon exposé en lecture rapide à toute vitesse, j'ai 30 secondes.

Autrement on pourrait penser à réduire par « (avec la/en) méthode rapide »...

Comment: Je pense que c'est la formulation la plus appropriée parce qu'en essence, "to speed read" c'est appliquer la technique du "speed reading". Même en anglais, selon moi le verbe vient du nom, et non l'inverse. Dans ce cadre d'« appliquer une technique », *faire de la lecture rapide* me semble logique et naturel.