# Quelle formulation incluant « lecture rapide » permet d'évoquer la technique sans signifier simplement « lire rapidement » ?

Tags: prépositions, formulation-idiomatique, ordre-des-mots, déterminants

Dans une [autre question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/52230) on identifie « lire selon la méthode de [lecture rapide](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecture_rapide) » pour [*speed-read*](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/speed-read/1000949) (Larousse en ligne anglais-français), plus généralement la « [lecture rapide](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lecture_rapide) », une « technique permettant d'accélérer la vitesse de lecture » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lecture_rapide)/Wikipédia ; aussi [GDT](https://vitrinelinguistique.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/fiche-gdt/fiche/19020397/lecture-rapide), [Usito](https://usito.usherbrooke.ca/d%C3%A9finitions/lecture#cd8cc2630f65965d), [Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/lecture), [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lecture%20rapide%2C*%20lecture%20rapide%2Cm%C3%A9thode%20de%20lecture%20rapide%2Ctechnique%20de%20lecture%20rapide&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3)).

Mais j'ai de la difficulté à arrimer le terme précédé du verbe semi-auxiliaire *faire* afin de ne pas empiéter sur le sens de base de « lire rapidement » (vite, faire un survol de) avec un objet comme le mot « texte » :

> J'ai [*faire*] [*déterminant*] lecture rapide [*préposition*] [*déterminant*] texte.

- Quelle combinaison de déterminants/préposition est la plus cohérente
  et fréquente, usuelle ?
- D'autre part, pense-t-on qu'il est meilleur d'employer le verbe « lire
  » (comme chez Larousse) avec « lecture rapide » et dans ce cas aussi,
  quelle combinaison de déterminants/préposition est la plus cohérente
  et fréquente, usuelle ?
- Y a-t-il d'autres tournures qui permettent d'exprimer ce que l'on
  veut dire ici et qui seraient naturelles ?

Comment: La notion de tournure "usuelle" ou "naturelle" me parait à relativiser quand on parle d'une expression qui est 1/ récente en francophonie 2/ issue d'un *noun-verb compound* qui s'adapte assez mal à notre langue et 3/ probablement usitée par une poignée d'experts...

Comment: @guillaume31 Oui c'est vrai. Je me contenterais de _cohérente_ et qui _s'énonce clairement_ ou se _dit facilement_, voire _qu'on emploierait spontanément à l'oral_. Bien je connaissais une personne qui disait posséder cette technique et je me demande comment elle aurait formulé ça... D'autre part je trouve que le _noun-verb compound_ s'adapte mal surtout quand on s'attache à reproduire sa structure, ça devient comme des œillères... comme ici c'est pas tant cette morphologie que des sens plus usuels sur lesquels on ne veut pas empiéter qui compliquent la donne, avec _bottle-keep(ing)_ aussi...

Comment: https://blog-gestion-de-projet.com/technique-de-lecture-rapide/ : « La lecture rapide (aussi appelée lecture experte ou ***lecture globale***) est une méthode qui permet de lire beaucoup plus vite, tout en retenant les aspects importants du texte »… « Sachez en outre que vous pouvez encore optimiser ce temps de lecture en couplant la lecture rapide avec d’autres méthodes de lecture, comme ***la lecture en diagonale***. »

Answer (score 1):

Hors contexte, "j'ai fait une lecture rapide du texte" me parait trop générique pour qu'on comprenne qu'il s'agit d'une technique particulière.
Un usager régulier de cette technique pourrait nous éclairer plus précisément, mais spontanément je dirais :

> J'ai parcouru le texte en lecture rapide